# How to replace an index.html file with another index.html stored in a repository in Github?

Tags: github, github-pages

currently my "Hello World" index file, in the master branch in github.com, points to the url address: https://user.github.io/

I have committed and push a new folder called the Repository Folder which contains a different index.html file and a .css file. How do I change the reference from the old "Hello World" file to the new index.html file in the Repository folder and it points to the url address: https://user.github.io?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to your repository setting for the repository which has GitHub Pages configured and change your branch or file path within a code for a particular branch from there.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response. Both the index.html and the Repository folder are both stored on the master. How do I change the index.html files in this case?

Comment: @wire_jp you just change folder to Repository and it should work.